# Let $\alpha$ be an automorphism of $\Bbb{F}[x]$ such that $\alpha(a)=a$ for all $a\in \Bbb{F}$. Show $\alpha(x)=ax+b$, $a,b\in \Bbb{F}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $\Bbb{F}$ be a field and $\alpha:\Bbb{F}[x]\rightarrow \Bbb{F}[x]$ be an automorphism such that $\alpha(a)=a$ for all $a\in \Bbb{F}$.
Show that $\alpha(x)=ax+b$ for some $a,b\in \Bbb{F}$.

Since all constant are mapped to itself and $\alpha$ is injective, $x$ cannot mapped into constant function. But I have no idea that why $x$ cannot be mapped into polynomial of degree at least $2$? I need some hint to tackle this question.

Comment: **Hint:** Let's say $\alpha(x)=x^2$. Since $\alpha$ is an automorphism, there exists a preimage of $x\in\Bbb F[x]$ (say $\beta$) such that $\alpha(x)=\alpha(\beta(x)^2)$ which implies $x=\beta(x)^2$. Can you see how this is a contradiction to the existence of $\beta$ ? A similar argument can be adapted for polynomials of degree $\gt 2$ using the homomorphism properties.

Comment: @PrasunBiswas A little confusion here. Is $\beta$ an element in the field or another automorphism?

Comment: To be precise, $\beta\in\Bbb F[x]$ (note that I said that $\beta$ is a preimage of $x\in\Bbb F[x]$).

Comment: @PrasunBiswas I think we can relax the condition to “$\alpha$ is a surjective homomorphism of rings with $1$”. Am I right?